# How can I print a figure to a pdf file with embedded greek letters or formulas in MATLAB?

Tags: matlab, latex, tex

I cannot find a solution to print a figure with embedded Greek letters using the print function (or the File Exchange function [export_fig()](https://ch.mathworks.com/matlabcentral/fileexchange/23629-export_fig) of Yair Altman).

While this functionality was available in earlier matlab releases (e.g. R2016a), the following code does not produce the desired result with version R2018a:

```
figure()
rng = 0:0.01:2;
plot(rng, sin(rng.*pi()))
text(1, 0.6, 'sin of {\alpha}')
print('simple_test_p', '-dpdf')
% export_fig('simple_test_e','-pdf', '-transparent')
```

[image]

While the text before '{\alpha}' is embedded in the resulting pdf file, alpha itself appears to be an image rather than an embedded font (see image).

I tried several different fonts to exclude the possibility of a missing default font (besides double-checking the font folder). Moreover, I used both latex and tex interpreters. Nevertheless, none of these procedures worked.

If this problem cannot be solved with Matlab, is there any other way to get a pdf file with embedded Greek letters and mathematical formulas?

I very much appreciate your help. Thank you in advance.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

MATLAB uses Unicode text everywhere. You should be able to simply do:

```
text(1, 0.6, 'sin of ')
```

If you can't type the Greek letters, you can always search for them on Google* and copy-paste them. I found the above [here](https://www.compart.com/en/unicode/U+1D6FC).

<sub>*or whatever your favorite search engine is.</sub>

Comment: Thank you very much @CrisLuengo. Do you also know a solution for (Latex) formulas? I very much appreciate your help.

Comment: @quantguy: No sorry, I don't know what changed in MATLAB for LaTeX to be output as an image. Are you embedding the figures in a LaTeX document? If so, simply write some placeholder text to the figure, and replace it in LaTeX.

Comment: That's exactly what I want. You're a genius. I'll go forward with this solution. Thank you so much.

Answer (score -1):

Or just use matplotlib, which gets along well with unicode:

```
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import numpy as np

x = np.arange(10000)
y = np.sin(np.pi * x * 0.001) 
plt.plot(x, y)
plt.ylabel(u"\u03B1")
plt.xlabel('β')
plt.savefig(r'<insert your path here>/sinewave.pdf')
plt.show()
```